# Is there a way to automate the CFX tags installation?

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-8

I'm currently in the process of re-installing a web farm of ColdFusion 8 servers (W2K8, IIS 7.5).

I have to install a number of CFX tags (C++) on each server to get the code running.

Is there a way to automate the installation of the CFX tags (regedit imports, VBS, PowerShell...)?

I found some link indicating that keys should be imported in the registry at: HKLM\Software\Allaire, but Allaire does not even exist in this branch (I believe that the instructions were true of older versions of CF).

I installed one of the tags manually and noticed that the file neo-runtime.xml was updated with:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<wddxPacket version="1.0">
  <header/>
  <data>
    <array length="18">
      <boolean value="true"/>
      <struct type="coldfusion.server.ConfigMap">
        <var name="session_variables">
          <boolean value="false"/>
        </var>
        <var name="application_variables">
          <boolean value="false"/>
        </var>
        <var name="server_variables">
          <boolean value="false"/>
        </var>
      </struct>
      <struct type="coldfusion.server.ConfigMap">
        <var name="cfx_http5">
          <struct type="coldfusion.server.ConfigMap">
            <var name="NAME">
              <string>cfx_http5</string>
            </var>
            <var name="CACHE">
              <string>true</string>
            </var>
            <var name="PROCEDURE">
              <string>ProcessTagRequest</string>
            </var>
            <var name="DESCRIPTION">
              <string/>
            </var>
            <var name="TYPE">
              <string>cpp</string>
            </var>
            <var name="LIBRARY">
              <string>D:\ColdFusion8\cfx\cfx_http5\cfxhttp5.dll</string>
            </var>
          </struct>
        </var>
      </struct>
```

Can I simply add the XML node to get it running?

Thanks in advance for any lead to the solution.

Comment: Since this is a question about configuring a CF server, it _might_ get better traction at [sf].

Comment: Have you tried creating an Archive from your CF installation and including the CFX tags?

Comment: @Al - Thanks for the tip, I'll also look next time. Unfortunately, there was nothing there for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try going into your ColdFusion Administrator, select Packaging & Deployment, ColdFusion Archives, and create a CAR file. Create a CAR file, and select your CFX tags. You should then be able to copy that CAR file to your other CF servers and deploy it, adding your CFX tags to each new installation one at a time.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. That was definitely what I was looking for. It would also be nice to be able to deploy the CAR file from the command line / script.